# cPanel - send 404 to a php page?

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue in a WordPress site on Hostgator where the htaccess file keeps disappearing.  Before you get all, "Check your plugins, dummy" I have the same install of this site running on a completely separate Hostgator account and it's running fine.  Furthermore, I have a local instance which, again, is running fine.  So if it *was* a plugin, the issue would be replicated on the other instances, but it's not.

My suspicion is someone who has access to the hosting account is tampering with it.  While that sounds paranoid, I can't rule anything out because htaccess files don't just delete themselves.

The bandaid fix has been to just reset permalinks once the site goes down.  Annoying, but simple.  What might be even neat would be to set my server 404 page to a php script that, when accessed, hits an endpoint I set up in WordPress to programmatically flush the rewrite rules, thus restoring the htaccess page, and then the 404 tries to forward them on again.  However, the suggestions on how to do this say putting the error page definitions in the htaccess page.  Which doesn't do me much good if the htaccess page is being deleted.

How stupid is this idea?  Please let me know in comments.

I'm open to other solutions, but I'm waiting on my hosting support to figure out how the file is being deleted because I assume others with the account info of tampering.

Comment: It would probably be **much** better to ensure your server has not become compromised. Your suggested solution might be a quick fix for this specific issue, but what about when you actually want to display a 404 error?

Comment: It's a WP site, so it has it's own 404 page.  Yes, I agree I'd want to make sure the host isn't compromised, but given the problem and circumstances, I think this is one individual doing just enough to be annoying rather than taking down the whole site.  I want hostgator to get off their backsides and respond to my ticket and figure out how/who/when the htaccess is being deleted.  In the mean time, I want a hidden fallback so the site is still accessible.  Maybe I'm aiming too high?

Comment: IMO, changing the server admin's password, limit permissions on the site folder should be plenty. You can also probably look through the access logs yourself. You can also look at each user's bash_history file.